# execute a Task asynchronously with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm getting quite confused about the push queues in google app engine.

All I want to do is run something asynchronously.  I have read the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push

But my code is giving 404 errors because it's calling `_ah/queue/default` which doesn't exist.

So here's some of my code:

```
class Notification implements DeferredTask, Serializable  {
    public void run() {/*do something asynchronously here*/}
}

//elsewhere....
DeferredTask notification = new Notification();
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();//getQueue("default");
TaskOptions task = TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(notification );
queue.add(task);
```

So do I now need to set up a servlet?  If so, should it be mapped to `/_ah/queue/default`, `/queue/default` or `/default` ?  And do I then deserialize the request input stream to reconstitute the Notification object, then just call the run method?  Seems a very convoluted way of doing it.

It does say in the documentation "You can use this queue immediately without any additional configuration." but that doesn't seem quite right if I need to start messing around with web.xml.

UPDATE
I'm not sure if using a DeferredTask is the correct thing to do.  I see in my admin panel that there are a whole load of tasks in the queue, but they all fail every time they run due to a 404 error.

Comment: You do not need to create/configure anything for a default queue to work. Which is exactly the error message that you see in the App Engine logs? Also, try `Notification notification = new Notification();`, and you don't need to use "implements Serializable", because DeferredTask already extends it.

Comment: I believe that TaskOptions will be configured with the URL `/_ah/queue/__deferred__` in this case, overriding the default URL for the default queue.  This is the URL associated with the built-in servlet for deferred tasks.  Neither the default queue nor the built-in servlet should need explicit configuration.  If you defer a task in the dev server, then open the Developer Console (`/_ah/admin`) in a browser and find the Task Queue panel, is there task in the default queue waiting to be executed?